# Web Speech API and data protection

Tags: data-protection, webspeech-api

If you are using the browser's (currently probably just chrome) build in web speech API:

```
var SpeechRecognition = SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition
var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
recognition.onresult = [...]
```

Where is the data processed? It seems like the API is run and evaluated completly locally - chrome even has an accessibility feature to create captions for english video that clearly downloads a solution to run completely locally, but I read that it is actually evaluated by google's servers e.g. in Midcamp's live captioning repo it says:

"Chrome supports the Web Speech API, a mechanism for converting speech to text on a web page. It uses Google's servers to perform the conversion. Using the feature sends an audio recording to Google (audio data is not sent directly to the page itself), along with the domain of the website using the API, your default browser language and the language settings of the website. Cookies are not sent along with these requests. More information can be found here: [Links to the Specification that do not directly relate to data protection]"

It also seems like Google's own demo doesn't have any rate limits which feels rather counterintuitive to Google's own speech recognition solutions they offer as a paid service. This confuses me.

If I want to include this API in a public project it is paramount that we know where the data is sent.

Is the Web Speech API executed locally?

Are there local or self-hostable alternatives?

Comment: I'm having the same interrogations but I can't find the answer. Did you have any luck ?

Comment: None. To me it seems obvious that right now if you use the web speech api with Chrome or Safari (the only browsers where it works) the data will be sent to Google or Apple. As far as I understand the intention is that eventually these APIs will ask your operating system to do the speech to text conversion, but until all desktop operating system can guarantee that such a system is available I doubt it will improve. It is still weird though that for embedded videos Chrome allows you to download their NN and evaluate stuff locally.

Answer (score 0):

The Web Speech API is an interface which is implemented by your browser. Each Browser like Firefox, Chrome, Safari, etc. has their own implementation.

Firefox is currently the only Browser where you can configure a specific service endpoint. Here one excerpt from their documentation:

> - Navigate to about:config
> - Set the preference `media.webspeech.service.endpoint` to https://dev.speaktome.nonprod.cloudops.mozgcp.net/ (this endpoint is for testing purposes only)
> - Navigate to Google Translate, click the microphone and say something.

For more Information see https://wiki.mozilla.org/Web_Speech_API_-_Speech_Recognition

Chrome and Safari are implementing the Web Speech API under the hood. You could not change this behavior on your own.

I am currently working on an proposal, how to extend this API to match requirements from privacy polices and offline usage. My proposal will be presented at The Web Conf 2023 - https://www2023.thewebconf.org/

Comment: Firefox is only  a browser, which doesn't implement `SpeechRecognition` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition#browser_compatibility